# IEにおいて、SVGをHTML内に直接記述した場合、他のブラウザと大きさが異なる

Tags: html, css, svg

IE11において、以下のようにHTML内に直接記述したSVGのスケーリングが、他のブラウザと異なります。

```css
#svg {
  width: 80%;
  
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 430 330" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="red" />
  <rect x="130" y="130" width="300" height="200" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Firefox, Chrome, Edgeなどでは横幅に合わせてアスペクト比を保持したままスケーリング(縦幅を自動で調節)しますが、
IEにおいては縦幅が固定になってしまいます。

IEにて、横幅に合わせてアスペクト比を保持したまま、縦幅を自動で調節させたいのですが、良い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[asamuzaK.jp : ♪Vector Vector, please. Oh, the mess I'm in (c) UFO](http://asamuzak.jp/html/483)を参照し、以下のようにwidthに応じてheightを計算し設定するjavascriptを書くことで解決しました。

*(実際に使用する場合は、IEのみに適用されるよう、if (document.documentMode)などで条件をつける必要があります。)*

```js
function resize_svg_width(elem) {
  function getAspect(o) {
    var y = o.split(' ');
    return y[3] / y[2];
  }

  z = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, '').width;
  a = z.match(/([0-9\.]+)px/)[1] * 1;
  b = getAspect(elem.getAttribute('viewBox'));
  elem.style.height = (a * b) + 'px';
}

var resize_event = function() {
  var target = document.getElementById("svg");

  resize_svg_width(target);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize_event, false);
resize_event();
```

```css
svg {
  width: 80%;
  
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 430 330" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="red" />
  <rect x="130" y="130" width="300" height="200" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: その例だと、IE以外にも適用されてしまいますよ
if(document.documentMode){
}
などで括る必要があります